# Consulta Mysql Fecha(date)

Tags: mysql

mi consulta:

Tengo un campo date en MySQL de fecha, y a la hora de hacerle un insert a la tabla no me acepta este formato: 'dd/MM/yyyy', porque creo que mysql acepta otro tipo de formato.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_peliculas
(codpeli char(5) primary key not null,
nompeli varchar(50) not null,
genero varchar(40),
fechaestreno date,
duracion varchar(40),
idioma varchar(20),
idsubtitulo int,
idcalidad int,
precio double); 

INSERT INTO TB_PELICULAS VALUES('P0001', 'X-men: Apocalipsis', 'Ciencia Ficción, Acción', '19/05/2016', '2 horas y 10 minutos','Inglés y Español Latino',1,1,50.0);
```

Cuando inserto lo de arriba, me aparece este error:

```
Incorrect date value: '19/05/2016' for column 'fechaestreno' at row 10.000 sec
```

¿ Cómo hago para que me acepte el formato: dd/MM/yyyy ?

Answer (score 2):

Yo no me complicaría.
Creo que es más facil guardar la fecha como aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss y cuando saques la fecha usar el lenguaje de programación como sea necesario para coger el dia, el mes etc para reformatearlo.
Por ejemplo, podrias hacer un explode con php para separar primero la fecha de la hora por un espacio y luego separar los elementos de la fecha haciendo otro explode por los guiones y la hora separandola por los dos puntos y asi tendrias cada numero de la fecha y de la hora, luego podrias crear un string ordenando esos elementos con el orden que quieres y los separadores que quieres.
Me parece un metodo sencillo.

Answer (score 1):

al parecer ya esa preguta ha sido resuelta aca en la plataforma (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624009/inserting-mm-dd-yyyy-format-dates-in-mysql)  pero yo prefiero manejar siempre ese campo tipo varchar si tu mismo vas hacer las inserciones, lo he tomado como experiencia